# updating angular packages with ng update to version 13 updates some package to 16

Tags: angular, package.json

I don't understand why after executing this command

**ng update @angular/core@13 @angular/cli@13**

Some packages' versiones got updated to version 16xx

I´m using node v16.20.2 and npm v8.19.4. I don't know if node version has to do with this issue

[image]

Here my initial versions before executing the ng update command.

[image]

I´m publishing this question just to try to understand what happened here.
I reached a solution. It´s more work but works. I updated manually each package one by one related with angular and some more like @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin, @typescript-eslint/parser, eslint-plugin-unicorn using this syntax:

npm i package@version --force

For example:
npm i @angular/animations@14.3.0 --force

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is correlated for your problem, but the right way to update angular version is this for what I know: https://update.angular.io/?v=13.0-16.0
Angular give a guide step by step to update angular version, so maybe the problem could be that.

Apart from that, some packages are not compatible with your old version of Angular and so they are also updated.

Comment: I´m aware of that angular oficial guide. In fact the command: ng update @angular/core@13 @angular/cli@13 is the first one on the guide. I am trying to update from version 12 to 14 through version 13

Comment: Yes, that was for direct you in the correct guide. For reply at your question, when you update the angular version, the command automatically search for the version compatible for the other packages because of the dependencies